# Readings for Noether

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm studying the theory of Noether but I have only 4 pages of lecture notes with no details or examples. Are there any good lecture notes or chapters you know about? In my lectures the basics of Noetherian modules and Noetherian rings are discussed and then both the weak and strong Nullstellenstatz (Hilbert).

Comment: If you're serious about reading and understanding her work, eventually everyone must (or rather at least should) read her original paper, the translation of which can be found here:  http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.2577

Comment: Well I was thinking about more like introduction with examples in modern algebra symbols.

Answer (score 1):

*This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.*

---

1. "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" by Atiyah & Macdonald
2. "Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry" by Eisenbud
3. Original [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.2577v1.pdf) by Noether as mentioned in the comments, translated into English and using modern mathematical symbols (similar notation as what you would find the the Zariski/Samuel "Commutative Algebra" 2-volume set).

The first two should cover more than enough to get you started. The first will make you do much more work on your own, the second is quite a tome, but filled with examples, should cover everything the first one does and more.